# What is the name of the functions $V\to V$ which map every 1-dimensional subspace of $V$ to an 1-dimensional subspace of $V$?

Tags: vector-spaces, terminology, projective-space

Motivation: the permutations of the projective space $P(V)$ can be regarded as the equivalence classes of such functions (two such functions, $f$ and $g$ are regarded to be equivalent if for every 1-dimensional subspace $L$ of $V$, $\{f(x):x\in L\}=\{g(x):x\in L\}$). I would call them projective functions but I'm afraid that this name means something else.

**Edit**

I definitely mean of all such functions, not only the homogeneous (or more specifically, the linear) ones.

Comment: I presume you are focusing on linear functions?

Comment: Aren't these just invertible linear transformations (quotiented by the scalars)?

Comment: @Joppy Yes, if OP is asking what I think they are asking then these are the projective linear maps, i.e., elements of $PGL(V)$, the coordinate-free analogue of $PGL_{n}(k).$

Comment: The actual functions on $V$ which send 1D subspaces to 1D subspaces form a "wreath product" - you have a direct product of symmetric groups $S_L$ for each line $L$ (not counting the origin) and also a (noncanonical) copy of the symmetric group $S_P$ (where $P$ is the set of lines, i.e. the projective space), and the group of all such functions is the wreath product $S_L\wr S_P$.

Comment: @runway44 OP has told me that they are indeed interested in *all* functions, not just linear ones. So I think you should strongly consider turning this into an answer.

Comment: I don't know that these functions have a name (other than "lifts" of functions on $\Bbb PV$), but my answer describes the structure of the set (really, monoid) of these functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to construct an arbitrary function $\phi:V\to V$ sending 1D subspaces to other 1D subspaces (which I will just call "lines" for short). Picking any two lines $L_1$ and $L_2$, we know $0$ must be mapped to a point on both lines $\phi(L_1)$ and $\phi(L_2)$, which is just $0$, so $\phi$ fixes $0$. It remains to see how $\phi$ can act on nonzero vectors. We can split this up into two parts: how $\phi$ acts on the set $P=\mathbb{P}V$ of all lines, and how it permutes points within lines.

For every function $\sigma:P\to P$, there are going to be $\phi$s which send lines $L$ to lines $\sigma(L)$. Note the restriction of $\phi$ to a line must be a bijection. Thus, we can decompose the set $\Phi$ of all such $\phi$s into

$$ \Phi = \bigsqcup_{\sigma:P\to P} \prod_{L\in P} \mathrm{Bij}(L,\sigma(L)) $$

where $\mathrm{Bij}(X,Y)$ denotes the set of bijections $X\to Y$ and the lines are considered to not contain $0$. As a monoid, this is a kind of "monoid wreath product" of the monoid of all $\sigma:P\to P$ and the direct product of symmetric groups $S_L$ for all lines $L$ (again, ignoring $0$). This might be easier to understand by looking at the subgroup $G$ of *invertible* $\phi$s.

First, we can construct a copy of $S_P$ within $G$ that permutes the lines themselves as follows. For each line $L$, choose a bijection $\ell_L:L\to k^{\times}$ (where $k$ is the base field), which induces a bijection between any two lines as $\ell_{L_2}\circ\ell_{L_1}^{-1}:L_1\to L_2$. Then, given any permutation $\pi\in S_P$, we can think of it as a function on $V$ (fixing $0$) by saying $\pi$'s restriction to any line $L$ is $\ell_{\pi(L)}\circ\ell_L^{-1}$. This givecs a copy of $S_P$ within $G$.

The subgroup of $G$ which fixes every line is a direct product $\prod_{L\in P}S_L$. Note this direct product intersects $S_P$ trivially, and that $S_P$ normalizes this direct product. Moreover, if $\phi\in\Phi$ is arbitrary (well, invertible) and induces a permutation $\pi$ of $P$ then $\phi\circ\pi^{-1}$ fixes each line so is an element of the direct product. That means

$$ G= \big(\prod S_L\big)\rtimes S_P \cong S_{k^{\times}}\wr S_P $$

is a wreath product.